# I can't figure out how to correctly call the information in my module to the program and make the calculations work?

Tags: function, module, fortran, subroutine

Basically what I have to do is read in a file called "sounding.txt" that has 100 rows of data. I'm reading that data in and doing different calculations from that data. I'm calculating the freezing level (FRZ), the dew point depression at 700mb (Tdd700), the total totals (TT), the K-Index (KI, and the SWEAT Level (SW). I'm then supposed to output that value into a new data file. The calculations are shown in the code and it seems like most of everything is right but I'm getting a few errors when I compile everything. The terminal errors state that the symbol "Tdd700" conflicts with the symbol from the module "soundingcalcs", that the symboll "T700" has no IMPLICIT type, that the symbol "Td700" has no IMPLICIT type, and that there's a rank mismatch in my argument "T850" at "KI=ki_calc(sounding)". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I would appreciate any help or advice.
 My module:

```
MODULE soundingcalcs

IMPLICIT NONE

 REAL ::  Tdd700, TT, T850, T500, Td850, T700, Td700
 REAL :: V850, V500, dd500, dd850

   contains

   ! This is where the internal module is located

   !##################################################################
   !This functions will calculate the K-Index.
   ! 
   !Accepts: temperature and dew point at different levels
   !Returns: KI-Index
   !#################################################################

  FUNCTION ki_calc(T850,T500,Td850,Tdd700)

  ! Calculate K-Index

  REAL, INTENT(IN) :: T850,T500,Td850,Tdd700
  REAL:: ki_calc

  ki_calc=((T850)-(T500))+(Td850)-(Tdd700)

  END FUNCTION ki_calc

  !################################################################
  !This subroutine will calculate the SWEAT Index
  !
  !Accepts: Total Totals, wind speed, dew point, and temperature
  !Returns: SWEAT Index value
  !################################################################

  SUBROUTINE sw_calc(Td850,TT,V850,V500,dd500,dd850)

  ! Calculate SWEAT Index

  REAL, INTENT(IN):: Td850,V850,V500,dd500,dd850
  REAL:: sw_value, TT

 sw_value=12.0*(Td850)+20.0*((TT)-49.0)+2.0*(V850) &
   +(V500)+125.0*(sin((dd500)-(dd850))+0.2)

  END SUBROUTINE sw_calc

 END MODULE soundingcalcs
```

My main program:

```
USE soundingcalcs

IMPLICIT NONE

CHARACTER(20), PARAMETER :: datafile = "sounding.txt"
CHARACTER(20), PARAMETER :: outfile = "hw9_NEIFERT.out"
CHARACTER(3) :: stname
REAL :: lat, long, elev, pres, temp, dewp, winddir, sw_value
REAL :: windspd, FRZ=0, MW=0, windmax, Td500, SW, KI
REAL :: T700, Td700, Tdd700, TT850, T500, Td850
REAL, DIMENSION(5,100) :: sounding
REAL, PARAMETER :: pi = 3.14159
INTEGER :: OpenStat=0, InputStat=0, day, mth, yr, hr, stnum
INTEGER :: count=0, i, j, log=0
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: flag = -999

sounding=flag

! Open the GEMPAK sounding file

open (unit=2, file=datafile, status="old", iostat=OpenStat)
IF (OpenStat > 0) STOP "Can't open file"

! Read in header and then read in data as array

read (unit=2, FMT="(8x,A3,15x,I8,10x,I2,I2,I2,1x,I4)") &
   stname, stnum, yr, mth, day, hr

read (unit=2, FMT="(8x,F6.2,14x,F6.2,10x,F7.1)") &
   lat, long, elev

read (unit=2, FMT="(////)")

read (unit=2, FMT=*, iostat=InputStat) sounding

! Set counter and maximum wind speed

DO i=1,100
  temp=sounding(2,i)
  IF (temp==flag) EXIT
  count=count+1
END DO

windmax=MAXVAL(sounding(5,:))

! Find temp, dew point, wind speed, directions

DO j=1, count
  pres=sounding(1,j)
  temp=sounding(2,j)
  dewp=sounding(3,j)
  winddir=sounding(4,j)
  windspd=sounding(5,j)

 IF (temp <= 0 .AND. log == 1) THEN
    FRZ=pres
    log=2
 END IF

  IF (pres == 850) THEN
    T850=temp
    Td850=dewp
    V850=windspd
    dd850=(((winddir)*(pi))/(180))
  END IF

  IF (pres == 700) THEN
    T700=temp
    Td700=dewp
  END IF

  IF (pres == 500) THEN
    T500=temp
    Td500=dewp
    V500=windspd
    dd500=(((winddir)*(pi))/(180))
  END IF

  IF (windspd==windmax) MW=pres

END DO

! Calculate 700 millibars dew point depression

Tdd700=(T700)-(Td700)

! Calculate the Total Totals

TT=((T850)-(T500))+((Td850)-(T500))

! Convert function and subroutine module subprograms into working 
! output values

KI=ki_calc(sounding)

! Open a file to output data

open (unit=3, file=outfile, status="new", iostat=OpenStat)
IF (OpenStat > 0) STOP "Cannot open file"

! Output header and values

write (unit=3, FMT="(6x,A15,4x,A3,10x,A11,1x,I8)") "Station ID:", &
stname, "Station #:", stnum

write (unit=3, FMT="(6x,A15,2x,I2,A1,I2,A1,I2,7x,A11,1x,I4,1x,A3)") &
"Date(MM/DD/YY):", mth, "/", day, "/", yr, "Time:", hr, "Z"

write (unit=3, FMT="(/A10,1x,F6.2,1x,A3,3x,A11,1x,F6.2,1x,A3,3x,&    
A11,1x,F8.2,1x,A1)")"Latitude:", lat, "deg", "Longitude:", long, "deg",&
"Elevation:", elev, "m"

write (unit=3, FMT="(/A16,1x,F6.2,1x,A2)") "Freezing Level:",FRZ,"mb"
write (unit=3, FMT="(A16,1x,F6.2,1x,A38)") "Total Totals:", TT
write (unit=3, FMT="(A16,1x,F6.2,1x,A38)") "K-Index:",KI
write (unit=3, FMT="(A16,1x,F6.2,1x,A2)") "SWEAT Index:", sw_value
write (unit=3, FMT="(A16,1x,F6.2,1x,A2)") "Max Wind Level:", MW, "mb"

! Close files

close(3)

close(2)

END PROGRAM sound_calc
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `use` the module, you import all its procedures, types, and variables.

So the error

```
REAL :: T700, Td700, Tdd700, TT850, T500, Td850
            1
sounding.f90:2.4:

USE soundingcalcs
    2
Error: Symbol 't700' at (1) conflicts with symbol from module 'soundingcalcs', 
use-associated at (2)
```

tells you that you declare a variable name that has already been taken by another variable in the module.

Either declare the variable only in the module, don't import it, or if you need a different variable, give it a different name.

So, for example, you have:

```
module my_mod
    implicit none
    real :: a = 1.0
contains
    function get_a()
        real :: get_a
        get_a = a
    end function get_a
end module my_mod
```

Then, if you only need the procedure, you can only import that:

```
program my_prog
    use my_mod, only: get_a
    real :: a
    a = 3e2
    print *, a
    print *, get_a()
end program my_prog
```

If you need a variable called `a` in your main program, and it needs to be different to the module's variable, and you need access to that module's variable as well, you can do something like this:

```
program my_prog
    use my_mod, only: get_a, b=>a
    implicit none
    real :: a
    a = 1.0
    b = 2.0
    print *, a, get_a()
end program my_prog
```

The second error is due to a rank-mismatch, simply put: The function `ki_calc` expects 4 arguments of scalar type `real`. But `sounding`, which you supply as the only argument, is a 2-d array with shape `(5, 100)`

I don't know what you want, but maybe something like

```
KI=ki_calc(sounding(1, 1), sounding(2, 1), sounding(3, 1), sounding(4, 1))
```

(This would indicate that `T850 == sounding(1, 1)` and `T500 == sounding(2, 1)` and so on.)

Comment: +1. However, I don't see the point in declaring a better function in the module: if it's because of protection against changes, you can use the `protected` or `parameter` attributes; if it's because of name clashes, you can use the `use :: mymod, b=> a` syntax.